# Jquery on click replace text positions

Tags: jquery

So, I've got one div `.drop-blue-rev`   which stores some text, and I've list of clients.
On `li` click event of `.menu-client-area`, I want to place text from `li` to div `.drop-blue-rev`and from div `.drop-blue-rev` place text to `li` which was clicked right now.
I've tried to do this:

```
$('.menu-client-area li').click(function () {           
        var storeLiText = $(this);
                var StoreClientAreaText = $('.drop-blue-rev');
                var StoreHelper = StoreClientAreaText;

        StoreClientAreaText.text(storeLiText.text());

        StoreLiText.text(StoreHelper.text());       
    });
```

I was thinking I could hold for some time value from div `.drop-blue-rev` with `StoreHelper`, while it will replace text with text from `li`, and then place value from `StoreHelper` to `li`. But it's not working, right after `StoreClientAreaText.text(storeLiText.text());`,`StoreHelper` will be equal `StoreClientAreaText`. Any ways to fix that?

JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/d4dw5/

Alright, I got this, it was just my stupidity - there is a syntax error, (storeLiText and StoreLiText).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d4dw5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to keep StoreClientAreaText.text() in StoreHelper rather then StoreClientAreaText object and then call StoreLiText.text(StoreHelper), because the way you have it now the StoreHelper and StoreClientAreaText are exactly the same object.

```
$('.menu-client-area li').click(function () {           
    var storeLiText = $(this);
    var StoreClientAreaText = $('.drop-blue-rev');
    var StoreHelper = StoreClientAreaText.text();

    StoreClientAreaText.text(storeLiText.text());

    storeLiText.text(StoreHelper);       
});
```

Comment: It doesn't helps, you can see your example live here http://jsfiddle.net/d4dw5/1/ Same result as mine

Comment: You have typo there (StoreLiText vs storeLiText). See http://jsfiddle.net/d4dw5/3/ and anyway you want to use .html() rather then .text().

Answer (score 0):

Changing `li`s `text` is not enough because you have `a` tags inside `li`s. Try this

```
$('.menu-client-area li').click(function () {   
  var StoreClientAreaText = $('.drop-blue-rev').text();

  $('.drop-blue-rev').text($(this).text());
  $(this).find("a").text(StoreClientAreaText);      
});
```